# ViewPager not showed after previous activity crash?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, horizontalscrollview, fragment-tab-host

There are two activitity, one is MainActivity, anthoer is SetttingActivity.

There are three fragments tabs with FragmemtTabHost in MainActivity.

The first tab contains a HorizontalScrollView with many items and a viewpager related those items inside HorizontalScrollView.

When I come to SettingActivity from MainActivity and trigger a bug which made on purpose, SettingActivitiy crashes and MainActivity come to front.

The first tab does load data again and viewpager adapter does set items again. notifyDatasetChanged and requestLayout are called. But nothing render in viewpager and HorizontalScrollView.

How to deal with this bug? I have no ideas.

Comment: Please, share your code. Make sure that you have onSaveInstanceState

Comment: No matter whether I have onSaveInstanceState, I load all data which is not empty and set items after recreation but nothing shows.